# Batch Files: Launch file IF xxxxxx is greater than xxKB

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement

I am currently faced with a problem, where I need to be able to launch another batch file if a file is under 10KB.

E.g. If xxxxx.txt is greater than 10KB launch stage2.bat

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%X in (file.foo) do if %%~zX GTR 10240 call stage2.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

This bat file checks whether the file size of xxxxx.txt is greater than 10KB (10280 bytes) and can assign some tasks depends on the result.

```
@echo off
cd C:\MyFolder\
set file="xxxxx.txt"

set maxbytesize=10280

FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('%file%') DO set size=%%~zA

if %size% GTR %maxbytesize% (
    //do stuff
) ELSE (
    //do stuff
)
```

Comment: Add some explanation to you answer please.